# RxJava unit test runs forever

Tags: unit-testing, rx-java

I'm using RxJava 1.1.2 and I want to write some unit tests. I'm using `RxJavaPlugins.getInstance().registerSchedulersHook()` and `RxAndroidPlugins.getInstance().registerSchedulersHook()` just like it's presented here https://medium.com/azimolabs/testing-rx-code-7918d7ee1680. My tests look like this:

```
@Test
public void xxxTest() {
    Assert.assertSame(Schedulers.immediate(), Schedulers.io());
    Assert.assertSame(Schedulers.immediate(), Schedulers.computation());
    Assert.assertSame(Schedulers.immediate(), Schedulers.newThread());
    Assert.assertSame(Schedulers.immediate(), AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
    presenter.xxx();
    verify(view, Mockito.only()).xxxResult();
}
```

and the method in `presenter` looks like:

```
public void xxx() {
    String[] items = new String[]{"one", "two", "three"};

    Observable.zip(Observable.from(items), Observable.interval(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS), (s, aLong) -> null)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnSubscribe(() -> view.xxxResult())
            .doOnUnsubscribe(() -> view.xxxResult())
            .subscribe();
}
```

When I run the test it starts, enters the `xxx()` method (which proves that the changing schedulers to immediate works - thanks to the `Assert.assertSame`) and never returns. Because of that the test runs forever and never gets to the line with `verify(view, Mockito.only()).xxxResult();`.

**Notice**: I'd rather not move up from 1.1.2 to the latest RxJava.

Some tests I performed so far:

- when I used `Schedulers.trampoline()` with using RxJava 1.1.2 it still runs forever (NOK)
- when I used `Schedulers.immediate()` with using RxJava 1.1.7 it doesn't run forever (OK)
- when I used `Schedulers.trampoline()` with using RxJava 1.1.7 it doesn't run forever (OK)
- when I used `Schedulers.immediate()` with using RxJava 1.3.0 it doesn't run forever (OK)
- when I used `Schedulers.trampoline()` with using RxJava 1.3.0 it doesn't run forever (OK)

It looks like RxJava 1.1.2 is broken in the area of `RxJavaPlugins.getInstance().registerSchedulersHook()` and `RxAndroidPlugins.getInstance().registerSchedulersHook()`.

Comment: Why don't you upgrade to the latest RxJava 1.x version if you know it works? Btw. [1.1.7](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/releases/tag/v1.1.7) introduced a new runtime hooking mechanism that allows proper overriding of schedulers.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [TestScheduler](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/schedulers/TestScheduler.html) class that allows you to "control" time during test.

```
@Test
public void xxxTest() {
    //     Arrange everything needed for the test
    TestScheduler scheduler = new TestScheduler();
    ... // replace all schedulers with test scheduler here
    Assert.assertSame(scheduler, Schedulers.io());
    Assert.assertSame(scheduler, Schedulers.computation());
    Assert.assertSame(scheduler, Schedulers.newThread());
    Assert.assertSame(scheduler, AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

    //     Act on the class
    presenter.xxx();
    scheduler.advanceTimeBy(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    //     Assert the result correctness
    verify(view, Mockito.only()).xxxResult();
}
```

There is a pretty good [blog post](https://medium.com/@fabioCollini/testing-asynchronous-rxjava-code-using-mockito-8ad831a16877) about this

Comment: Hi, see my edit. And why did you added a link to JS?

Comment: Fixed the link. Why would you use the `TestScheduler`? It gives you great flexibility like writing a test, that check if `xxxResult()` is *not* called after 1.5 seconds, etc. I'm using RxJava 1.1.3 and this method works like a charm